# Add /blog to the "post" post type url

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, blog

This question was already asked million times, but I do have an issue with the very simple solution of adding `/blog/%postname%` to the permalink structure.

I've installed several custom post types an d I use the [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) plugin to have a permalink structure of `example.com/cpt_name/parent_cat/child_cat/postname`. This works really well. Now I wanted to add `/blog/` to all my blog posts (default WordPress *Post* post type). So I added `/blog/%postname%` to my permalink structure and it works well. That was pretty simple...

BUT I now checked the permalink for my custom post types. They are `example.com/blog/cpt_name/parent_cat/child_cat/postname` now, which is definitely not what I waned... Do you know a solution that should work in this case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this by adding this line of code to your Register_post_type $args Function array:

$args array

```
'with_front' => false,
```

this will remove the blog from the front of the CPT that you add this line.

Remember to flush permalinks after you add it and save.

from the codex:

> 'with_front' => bool Should the permalink structure be prepended with
>   the front base. (example: if your permalink structure is /blog/, then
>   your links will be: false->/news/, true->/blog/news/). Defaults to
>   true.

you can see further reference here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

or just ask!

Comment: I just saw, that `blog` is also present on author archive pages. How can I remove it from there? The current url is: `example.com/blog/author/{author name}`

Comment: That's not the normal behavior.  Have you tried removing the other plugins that you originally set up?  You said in your original question:  "So I added /blog/%postname% to my permalink structure and it works well. That was pretty simple."  maybe what you did there affected more than you were expecting?

Comment: It actually needs to be added into the rewrite key as an array:

```'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false ),```